# grails console execution error

Tags: grails

Environment

- Grails 1.2.2
- Ubuntu 9.10
- IntelliJ 9.0.3

Everything works fine in IntelliJ. When I execute "grails console" in the project root I get the following

```
Error executing script Console: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed, SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 2: illegal string body character after dollar sign;                           
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 2, column 10.                                                                                                  
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! In the scaffolding directory the file "Controller.groovy" somehow made its way there. Removing this file solved the problem. Lesson learned - when seeing a template parsing error look closely at the templates directory.